# How can I search Google Voice for a phone number in only my text messages?

Tags: search, google-voice, sms, google-custom-search

In Google Voice, I can search for a phone number and see all the calls and text messages with that phone number.

How can I limit the search to just text messages?  I tried using adding `in:text` similarly to email search mechanisms but I got nothing in the results.

Answer (score 2):

In the search box add `in:sms` to limit the results to just text messages:

`> 2125551212 in:sms`

The above will search for all text messages with the phone number `(212) 555-1212`.

You can also add other Gmail like search terms, such as date limiters, e.g.,
`before:2016-08-01 after:2016-06-15`.